# Magento 2 why area code is showing wrong?

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, event-observer, rest-api, area

we placed order from magento frontend checkout when we check area code from this -

```
$this->_checkState->getAreaCode()
```

then we are getting area code is "webapi_rest"

it must be frontend.

Comment: M2 place orders through API. So the area code is correct.

Comment: @SohelRana but then how to identify that order is placed from rest API or frontend or any other platform?